# control interpreter - javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider this example:

```
alert(mood());
```

Now the function mood show up a div containing two radio elements say happy and sad, the user selects either happy or sad. Whatever the user selects must be returned through the function mood and alerted by the alert function

```
○happy    ●sad
```

Now the result is not expected. Before the user selects happy or sad, the interpreter goes through the function mood and as no value is being returned it alerts "undefined". I want the interpreter to wait for a while till the user selects any option.

My whole application is struck.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: You'll need an event-based solution, this is not going to work.

Comment: @Teemu What do you mean by that?

Comment: Please include the minimal code in your question that reproduces your problem. Otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Some kind of modal dialog implementation, the event which currently triggers the alert, should open a dialog, there's an event listener listening change of selections or clicks on separate OK button. Then call the alert in that handler.

Comment: @frank It is a code of more than 100 lines and i have used my own made library. It would take much time to understand it. :(

Comment: In that case I suggest that you reduce the code to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem that you are asking us to help with. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: return a promise from mood, then do the alert when mood resolves the promise with the users choice, if you are using jquery then you can look into examples that use the deferred object or articles like this explain it quite well http://dailyjs.com/2014/02/20/promises-in-detail/

Comment: or pass mood a call back with does the alert

Comment: @Quince : I can't understand Please give an eg.